# why does my right arrow asterisks art in python work?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

essentially my python assignment was to make a right arrow of "*" using for loops, I did it but, I have no clue how or why it works and I want to understand. Could someone explain my own code to me?

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePAOS.png)

Comment: I would recommend replacing the image with typed code. Also, it may be a good idea to state what you do not understand, or how you are trying to approach the code to understand it.

Comment: Hi there! Can you please add your code directly to the question. External links are discouraged

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.